# URI Too Large after 3rd insertion of html elements block

Tags: javascript, jquery

The error is:

```
NetworkError: 414 Request-URI Too Large  - http://localhost:3000/po/orders/new?supplier_id=2&utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=ZWwmhZMoHKCl......
```

Here is the jquery code responding to the change of one element of `quote_id`:

```
$(function (){
  //refresh for newly inserted element.
    $(document).on('change', "[id^='order_order_items_attributes'][id$='_quote_id']", function (){
    $.get(window.location, $('form').serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

After 3 insertions of the elements block, then there is `URI Too Large` error and the page stops responding any change on the html page. It seems that it can only take max 2 insertions.

Our question is that the size of inserted html block is the same for every insertion, why the error comes up with the 3rd insertion? Is the configuring web server the only way to solve the issue if the html block size can't be reduced?

Here is inserted html block:

```
<div class="fields">
<div class="input select required order_order_items_quote_id">
<label class="select required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_quote_id">
<select id="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_quote_id" class="select required span5" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413726997141][quote_id]">
</div>
<div class="input string required order_order_items_product_name">
<label class="string required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_product_name">
<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_product_name" class="string required span5" type="text" size="50" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413726997141][product_name]">
</div>
<div class="input text required order_order_items_product_spec">
<label class="text required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_product_spec">
<textarea id="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_product_spec" class="text required span5" rows="2" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413726997141][product_spec]" cols="40"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="input decimal required order_order_items_unit_price">
<label class="decimal required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_unit_price">
<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_unit_price" class="numeric decimal required span5 span5" type="number" step="any" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413726997141][unit_price]">
</div>
<div class="input integer required order_order_items_qty">
<div class="input string required order_order_items_unit">
<label class="string required control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_unit">
<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_unit" class="string required span5" type="text" size="50" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413726997141][unit]">
</div>
<div class="input string optional order_order_items_item_note">
<label class="string optional control-label" for="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_item_note">简注</label>
<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141_item_note" class="string optional span5" type="text" size="50" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413726997141][item_note]">
</div>
<input id="order_order_items_attributes_1413726997141__destroy" type="hidden" value="false" name="order[order_items_attributes][1413726997141][_destroy]">
<a onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;" href="#">删除产品</a>
</div>
```

Comment: If possible, can post `html` ? Thanks

Comment: what's in the returned script? Too many unknowns here

Comment: The code above was not firing up and there was no execution of the code after that.

Comment: Several elements not appear to have closing tags ? Can post `form` element `html` ? `remove_fields` function ? Thanks

Comment: The complete html code would be too messy if displayed (the code is generated by ruby erb file)!. What remove_fields does is to set _destroy flag to be true and hide the elements within div 'fields'.